# bash: find all files in a directory and use part of the name as argument for a command

Tags: bash, find

I need to get all of the jpg files in a directory, and execute the following command on each one:

```
mycommand -in <imagebasename>.jpg -out <imagebasename>.tif --otherparam paramvalue
```

I thought about:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mycommand -in {} -out {}.tif --otherparam paramvalue\;
```

but this will pass something like "./<imagebasename>.jpg" to mycommand.
I need to pass <imagebasename> only instead.

I don't need to process the directories recursively.

Comment: Are you trying to find files recursive directories too with respect to the current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'mycommand -in $0 -out "${0%.*}.tif" --otherparam paramvalue' {} \;
```

This will pass command of the form `mycommand -in <imagebasename>.jpg -out <imagebasename>.tif --otherparam paramvalue` to `-exec`.

EDIT: For removing leading `./`, you could say:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'f={}; f=${f/.\//}; echo mycommand -in "${f}" -out "${f%.*}.tif" --otherparam paramvalue' {} \;
```

(Note that the interpreter for `-exec` has changed.)

Comment: this will produce `mycommand -in ./imagebasename.jpg -out ./imagebasename.tif --otherparam paramvalue`.
How to strip the leading "./" ?

Comment: As my answer was based on yours in one of my questions... let's just leave your answer! This is endogamy :D

Comment: @fedorqui Nope, I wouldn't think or say so.

Comment: @fedorqui On the contrary, it's a matter of figuring where to apply a given solution.  *Even that* takes something.

Comment: @devnull I mean endogamy in the funny sense: us using and reusing questions and answers. As both your solution and mine became very similar, I now prefer to keep yours as what I wrote was based in what you taught me.